# Get return parameter of jQuery function inner blade.php Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a jQuery function that checks if Flash is enabled:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function isFlashEnabled()
            {
                var hasFlash = false;
                try
                {
                    var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
                    if(fo) hasFlash = true;
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
                }
                return hasFlash;
            }

    });
</script>
```

I want get the return hasFlash variable value (false or true) in my page.blade.php and check inner "@if" helper if flash is enabled:

```
@if (hasFlash())
 //if Flash is Enabled do this
 @else
 //do anything
@endif
```

Is this the right way?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Well Javascript can't work directly with php!
you need to do some ajax stuff yourself or write your code with a mixture of javascript and html.
instead of:

```
@if (hasFlash())
 //if Flash is Enabled do this
 @else
 //do anything
@endif
```

in javascript do:

```
if (hasFlash()){
 // ajax/cal a php page directly for this function
 // you can bypass arguments from js (easier but not secure) or use database & session (hard to do but secure)
}else{
 // ajax/cal another php page directly for this function
 // parameter bypass is the same as above
}
```

or if your code is more simpler then you can just write it directly with js.

you can also manipulate page (html) with jquery and use ajax to get content from php and add it to the page

**Edit:** ok let me explain with a sample senario:
Let's say when flash is enabled you want to have a flash player content and when flash is disabled you want to display a notary text.
I assume you wanted to do like this:

```
@if (hasFlash())
    //if Flash is Enabled do this
    echo '<media........>'; //whatever you html is.
@else
    echo '<p>Your flash disabled. ...</p>'; //whatever your error is.
@endif
```

Easiest way around this problem, that I suggest, is to manipulate your html after you detected client has no flash, like this:

in HTML:

Your flash disabled. ...

and in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isFlashEnabled() {
        var hasFlash = false;
        try {
            var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
            if (fo) hasFlash = true;
        } catch (e) {
            if (navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
        }
        return hasFlash;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(!isFlashEnabled()){
            $('#flash_container').css('display','none');
            $('#no_flash_container').css('display','');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**But,** you want to call some php functions when user has no falsh then you should do it by:
1. create a php file with your function in it.
2. run `$.get('url to php file created in 1');` in javascript if.
3. use session/database/http_params to transfer php variables between your pages.

If you still need more help I think it's best to read some documentations/wiki first.